How to repair a toilet drain pipe that is taller than the toilet flange
My toilet started leaked and the base and I took it off and realized that my drain is taller than the flange. I think a little bit of that was caused by my shed settling after 8 inches of rain in 1 storm. We normally get 12 inches a year. It is also slightly higher towards the rear of the toilet compared to the front. Is there a simple way to fix this or do I need to cut the pipe and completely redo this? 

Your toilet is in a shed?

You could also put a plywood platform around it to raise the toilet.

@Huesmann Yes, it is a vey large shed that’s been converted to an extra living space/man cave.

@DrMoishePippik its not current leaking now after putting a different flange spacer, but I fear that the drain will crack overtime. Could I just add the plywood in the same dimensions as the toilet base?
